# Plotting Irregular DateTime Data with a predefined X Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have time series data where the time component occurs at irregular intervals. Currently when I plot this data, the x axis labels show irregular times that match up with the points I've sent to the chart.

I'd like the x axis labels to appear at regular time intervals (say hourly), and have the points be plotted in an appropriate position. For example, a point with a time value of 1:30 AM would show up halfway between the 1 and 2 AM x axis labels.

I have a codepen (see below) that I've been making changes to in order to try to get the desired output but I've had no luck so far.

https://codepen.io/mprothme/pen/xvqZyQ

Actual Sample Code Below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Test Time Points'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: { 
      millisecond: '%H:%M:%S.%L',
      second: '%H:%M:%S',
      minute: '%H:%M',
      hour: '%H:%M',
      day: '%e. %b',
      week: '%e. %b',
      month: '%b \'%y',
      year: '%Y'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    min: 0
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
    pointFormat: '{point.x:%H:%M}: {point.y:.2f} '
  },

  plotOptions: {
    spline: {
      marker: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  },

  colors: ['#6CF'],

  series: [{
    name: "Time Series 1",
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2019, 10,  9, 10,5), 1],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 10,  9, 10,11), 1.1],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 10,  9, 10,15), 1.3],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 10,  9, 10,23), 1.5],
      [Date.UTC(2019, 10,  9, 10,25), 1.2]

    ]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `xAxis.tickInterval = 60 * 60 * 1000 (an hour in milliseconds)`.

**Code:**

```
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
      text: 'Date'
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    tickInterval: 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s21hjgtd/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval